# groupby and count a pandas dataframe containing a single column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

Is there an efficient way to group by and create a count col in a  data frame containing a single column.

I tried but involves creating an extra col in original dataframe i.e. in df in this example.

```
item={'colx':['a','b','a','c']}

df=pd.DataFrame(item)
df
colx
0   a
1   b
2   a
3   c
df['row_count']=1
df.groupby(['colx'])['row_count'].sum().reset_index()
​
colx    row_count
0   a   2
1   b   1
2   c   1
```

Comment: I think you're looking for pd.Series.value_counts() https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: that can be a workaround. But is there a more general groupby way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('colx')['colx'].agg(row_count='size' ).reset_index()
```

```
    colx    row_count
0      a    2
1      b    1
2      c    1
```

Comment: @itthrill, did the solution worked for you?